# Book on the rigorous construction of logic and set theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, propositional-calculus

Is there a book out there that discusses the construction of logic and set theory from the ground up?

Many of the logic books that I've found suffers from one main problem: it doesn't define things in the right order. For example:

1- propositions are statements which can either be true or false

2- predicates are ... (has references to propositions)

3- quantifier are ... (has references to predicates and propositions)

4- an axiom system contains a finite number of ... countable set of ... etc.

So the problem becomes: what does 'finite' mean? what is a 'number'? what is a 'countable'? have you even defined what a 'set' is?

In other words, it goes from step 1, step 2, step 3, refers to step 513, step 4, step 5, ...

I am aware of these concepts beforehand, but it would be nice to know the proper sequence of definitions (instead of defining something in terms of other things that have yet to be defined).

Comment: An exposition having a step by step construction and logical building up concepts and that covers most parts of what you have asked, is the book named "The Topology Problem Solver" by Emil G. Milewski.

Here is the [link](https://www.amazon.com/Topology-Problem-Solvers-Solution-Paperback/dp/B010WFJ1ES)

There might certainly be many other such expositions, but this came to my mind first.

Comment: Some hints: G.Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory: Volume 1, Mathematical Logic and Volume 2](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&printsec=frontcover) and W.Felscher, [Lectures on Mathematical Logic Volume I-III](https://books.google.it/books?id=xtEVV_Xk2tUC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Of possible interest is [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661513/foundation-of-formal-logic/2661741#2661741) to the Mathematics Stack Exchange question [Foundation of Formal Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661513/foundation-of-formal-logic).

Comment: Do you really believe there is something like 'the proper sequence of definitions'? In fact, that there can even be something like a 'step 1'?

Comment: Well, people don't use hilbert spaces to define sets. I believe that choosing the undefined terms we put in play is a topic we could afford to be iffy at. But, actual definitions should leave no room for hand wavy-ness.

Comment: You might think of such statements as informal commentary to aid in getting "the big picture." Like comments in computer programming source code. You can say, for example, that ZFC has "countably many" axioms in a presentation of the axioms, but you don't use this notion when formally proving theorems in ZFC.

Comment: I think informal comments do put things in proper context. Much like in programming, "the goal" or "what the author is going for" is often not immediately apparent when reading just the definitions. These are very important, but precise definitions are important as well.

Comment: Also, thanks very much for all the book references. I couldnt comment on them at the moment as I have yet to go through them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA could you please post an answer with the Tourlakis sources so that I could accept it. I found a copy and It's definitely what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see:

- GeorgeTourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory: Volume 1, Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2003) and [Volume 2: Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=nparMXao59QC&pg=PA1).

Comment: Are there any answer keys? I'm getting stuck on some questions, but the book just keeps on going on to new topics.