# Seeking a Rigorous Introduction to Mathematical Logic: Book Recommendation Needed

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

I would like to study mathematical logic, but I have very little previous background in this subject.

My knowledge is limited to some very basic concepts, such as atomic statements and how they are denoted by letters, creating new statements using connectives and understanding some of their equivalences.

**I am seeking a recommendation for a reference book that meets specific criteria :**
The book should be entirely rigorous, covering a substantial portion of the subject, and suitable for someone studying mathematical logic for the first time.

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: There's an answer here (and another in the comments) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483122/highly-rigorous-logic-book

Comment: @ancientmathematician thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent book which is pretty rigorous, covers a substantial portion of the subject, and is aimed at someone studying mathematical logic for the first time is Joseph Mileti's *Modern Mathematical Logic* (CUP, 2022).

It's OK, but not great. And the same goes, I think, for other candidate all-in-one texts that aim to cover a substantial portion of the subject all between one pair of covers. It is probably much better to chunk up the subject just a bit and choose from the best entry-level books on the different main areas. For pointers on how to do that, see *Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide* which [you can freely download here](https://logicmatters.net/tyl).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for making an excellent guide. i downloaded and i'm reading through it.